# Should users be informed when a question is flagged/vote to close rather than after it is closed?

Tags: discussion

I just flagged a question as 'too broad' and noticed that there is a helpful bit of text suggesting how to fix it.

However I've realised that that text is only seen by the asker *after* a question is closed (unless I'm missing something in the process due to lack of experience).

I think it would be better to inform the asker via the mailbox that their question has been flagged, giving the text from the close reason, as soon as a flag is raised (or in low rep user cases like mine once it has been approved).

This way an asker would have a chance to improve their question before it is closed.

Comment: A question being on hold is not the end of the world. That's the *purpose* of it, for the author to take their time and improve the question. When the edit is made, it's put into the review queue and reopened if deemed to be applicable for such. The system generally works.

Comment: I think notifying the OP _before_ we reach consensus can be quite confusing, especially if the OP is brand new and the flags / close votes aren't correct (which isn't exactly rare). That said, it only takes 250 rep points to be able to [see pending close votes on your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). Isn't that good enough?

Comment: I don't think that's good enough, no. It's mostly new users who get close votes and those are the ones who really need to get the best feedback.

Comment: @ClaraOnager: which they get when the post is closed. Giving them a message earlier only serves to confuse and upset.

Comment: How can a message informing them that their question may be put on hold confuse and upset _more_ than a message saying their question is 'on hold'?

Comment: @J.Steen It's hard for bad questions to be closed before someone posts an answer, and a lot harder for questions to be re-opened.

Comment: @simonzack If they're bad, they should be closed, so I don't see the problem?

Comment: @J.Steen It does seem to be harder to get a question reopened after it has been closed. I personally had to make several edits and flags to get one of mine reopened despite it being a relatively minor change that was required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678445/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-implement-email-functionality-without-an-email-client

Comment: @ClaraOnager It is hard, yes. Questions are (usually - mistakes are made) closed for a reason. However, you deleted that question before it had a real chance to be reopened. It was visible to the community for five days, while closed. You (much later) undeleted it, edited it, and it was reopened. That proves to me that the system works. If very slowly, sometimes.

Comment: FWIW this is what happens when question is flagged / voted as duplicate: dupe-banner is [shown to asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/165773) immediately

Comment: If any of my comments come off as, hmm, aggressively arrogant - that is not my intention. SO (and SE in general) deals with thousands of utterly banal and frankly idiotic questions every day and there are only so many of us willing to do reviews properly. I realise having your question closed sucks. But it *isn't* the end of the world. That's why the system is there.

Comment: @gnat If that was extended to other close votes I think it would really improve it

Comment: @J.Steen If it upsets you to play the SO game then you should stop playing rather than complaining about the players

Comment: @ClaraOnager *I'm* not upset. We're just overwhelmed. I'm not complaining. I'm explaining. There's a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it would be better to inform the asker via the mailbox that their question has been flagged, giving the text from the close reason, as soon as a flag is raised (or in low rep user cases like mine once it has been approved).

Yes, it would benefit the author if they knew as soon as possible that their question should be fixed, but still not a good idea.

As I recall, a flag to close a question is deemed helpful ("approved", as you put it) when someone puts an actual vote to close on the question after you've flagged it. So in practice this can mean that as soon as two people agree that the question should be closed, then your flag is deemed helpful, and the OP would be notified.

Flags are mistakenly raised. Votes to close are mistakenly raised. If the OP is notified as soon as a vote is put in (which is what you are suggesting), there would be a significant number of cases where the OP is notified on the basis of a mistaken vote. They'd just needlessly scramble to fix their question.